# Changing borders in matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, edit, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to change the political borders of countries in Basemap permanently. How do I go about doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no smart way to do this. You can modify the data in the `mpl_toolkits/basemap/data` folder. The coastlines come from the GSHHS dataset so replace the `gshhs*` files with other `gshhs` formatted data. If your data is not in `gshhs` format then it will be a tough task, but you could [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the `drawcoastlines` method on a basemap.

Good luck!